# PouchDB + Superlogin + Angular 2 / Ionic 2

Tags: angular

Does anyone have a working version of Superlogin and an Ionic 2 / Angular 2 front end they can share? Like [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683287/pouchdb-superlogin-angularjs-2/46780667#46780667) I am following the excellent tutorials from [Josh Morony](https://www.joshmorony.com/offline-syncing-in-ionic-2-with-pouchdb-couchdb/) and the [Superlogin documentation](https://github.com/colinskow/superlogin) but am getting stuck. The tutorial doesn't cover important aspects like password-recovery or social authentication and the documentation assumes reader already knows how Superlogin works.